# Use both onClickListener and onLongClickListener in listview Android 1.6

Tags: android, listview, onlongclicklistener

I am using both `onClickListener` and `onLongClickListener` for a **TextView** in a **ListView**. I see that in Android 1.6, the long click listener is fired along with the on click listener meaning both are fired when I long click. But this is not the case in the future versions. Is there any fix for this?

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

  if (convertView == null) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
    row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row, parent, false);
  }

  TextView tv = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.tv);

  tv.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
      @Override
      public void onClick(View view) {
        showMessage();
      }
  });

  tv.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
      @Override
      public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
        showLongMessage();
      }
  });
}
```

Comment: What "fix"? The fact that it fired both in 1.6 is certainly a bug.

Comment: By fix, I mean, is there any way to prevent this problem.

Comment: Are they called consistently in the same order?  Which?

Comment: Are the callbacks called at exactly the same time when you make a longclick?

Comment: First the longClick event is performed followed by the clickevent.

Comment: When I place my finger for 2 sec, onlongclick listener is called       and when I lift my finger, click listener is called.

Comment: http://strangeoptics.blogspot.com/2011/09/android-how-to-figure-out-long-click.html

Comment: You should check the android documentation, it's quite useful: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnLongClickListener.html

Answer (score 127, accepted):

Did you return boolean `true` at the end of [`OnLongClickListener`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnLongClickListener.html) to indicate you don't want further processing?

Answer (score 14):

I think you you should use  OnItemLongClickListener() instead of OnLongClickListener().

See [developers website](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener.html) for further response

Answer (score 13):

```
TextView t1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
t1.isClickable();

t1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
});

t1.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Long Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return true;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 3):

```
itemToClick.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
   @Override
    public void onClick(View v)      { 
      //do your logic on click 
     });
itemToClick.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
      // do your logic for long click and remember to return it 
        return true; }});
```