# Android: How to code an AlertDialog with onClickListener and onLongClickListener

Tags: java, android, onclicklistener, android-alertdialog, onlongclicklistener

Like the title says. I have coded onClickListener to my AlertDialog but i don't know how to put there onLongClickListener.

This is my code:

```
private void addRecipeMethod() {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setTitle("Title");
    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(getBaseContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, getArrayList("ListOfRecipes"));
    builder.setAdapter(adapter, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            List<String> list = new ArrayList<>(getArrayList("ListOfRecipes"));
            getArrayListRecipes(list.get(which));
            List<String> listMain = new ArrayList<>(getArrayList("ListMain"));
            listMain.addAll(getArrayListRecipes(list.get(which)));
            saveList(listMain, "ListMain");

            adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(getBaseContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, getArrayList("ListMain"));
            listView.setAdapter(adapter);





            //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "you have clicked " + list.get(which) , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
    builder.show();
}
```

PS. void addRecipeMethod is called when Menu Item is clicked

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Use both onClickListener and onLongClickListener in listview Android 1.6](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4621439/use-both-onclicklistener-and-onlongclicklistener-in-listview-android-1-6)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create `AlertDialog` with custom layout like this

```
    AlertDialog.Builder dialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    // ...Irrelevant code for customizing the buttons and title
    LayoutInflater inflater = this.getLayoutInflater();
    View dialogView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.alert_label_editor, null);
    dialogBuilder.setView(dialogView);


    Button button = (Button)dialogBuilder.findViewById(R.id.btnName);

    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
       @Override
       public void onClick(View view) {

         //Commond here......

       }
   });

    button.setOnLongClickListener(new OnLongClickListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return false;
        }
    });

    AlertDialog alertDialog = dialogBuilder.create();
    alertDialog.show();
```

Add Button in `alert_label_editor` xml and add `setOnLongClickListener` for that Button

```
    Button button = (Button)dialogBuilder.findViewById(R.id.btnName);

    button.setOnLongClickListener(new OnLongClickListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return false;
        }
    });
```